# How to loop multiple variable from first row of table PHP

Tags: php, html

I based on the sales person to loop and insert the data with 3 rows into database [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blGNT.png). But I cannot insert the category with 2 times with 2 sales person based on the first row, it keep get the last row of category data and insert to database. Like below image of [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teJZY.png).

[image: After insert data]

[image: Table to select the data before insert to database]

```
$product_type = $request->post('product_type');
$emp_amount = $request->post('amount');

 foreach($_POST['employee'] as $index => $employee_list){
                    
         $statement = $this->db->prepare('
          INSERT INTO `selling_employee` (
          invoice_no, payment_id, category, sale_person, amount, created_at
          ) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
          ');
         $statement->execute([
         $invoice_id, $payment_id, $product_type[$index], $employee_list, $emp_amount[$index], $created_at
         ]);   
                
 }
```

Any solution how to detect the first row got more than sales person and insert multiple same data based on first row.

Comment: Show the output of `var_dump($_POST);` please

Comment: @ADyson cannot print the output because it is modal form with angularJs

Comment: Not sure how that's relevant. Are you really meaning that the request is sent by AJAX? in that case You'll be able to see anything that PHP echoes in the response tab of that request, which appears in the browser's network tab. Or if you prefer, you could log the data to a file. Nothing should be preventing you from debugging this.